# Aerospike golang ListInsertOp multiple values

Tags: go, aerospike

Does the ListInsertOp in golang aerospike client support inserting an array of elements ?

If I use https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#ListAppendOp, and pass an array ([]string), it just appends the whole array as one value in the list. Am I using it wrong or is there another way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListAppendOp` is a variadic function accepting arbitrary number of arguments of type `interface{}`. If you call it passing your array, it will receive a slice of `interface{}` (`[]interface{}`) with a single element which is your array.

You need to convert your array to a slice of `interface{}` and expand it using `...` when passing it to the function:

```
a := []string{"a", "b", "c"}

s := make([]interface{}, len(a))
for i, v := range a {
  s[i] = v
}

ListAppendOp("bin1", s...)
```

Example of passing an array to a variadic function:
https://play.golang.org/p/541aJ6dY6D

From the specs:
[Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

Comment: Have u tried this ? I remember trying this and getting only one array entry in the list instead of 3 string entries. Btw, I tried the same with ListInsertOp (because I'm trying to prepend values to list instead of append)

Comment: Maybe the way I am confirming the same is wrong. Is there some aql query to get the number of values in the list ?